# Remove control (Play, pause etc..) on HTML5 Video Tag

Tags: javascript, html5-video

Is there a way to remove the control button with html5 video tag.

```
<video controls>
 <source src="video.ogv">
 <source src="video.mp4">
</video>
```

I'm pretty sure there is a way to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't set it at all
`controls` is a boolean property so you can either set it or not set it.
`<video controls>` is the same as `<video controls="controls">`

```
<video>
  <source src="video.ogv">
  <source src="video.mp4">
</video>
```